# What's the best option to put multiple images inline with reportlab?

Tags: reportlab

I wan't to create some kind of catalog with reportlab (images with labels), but I can't put more than one image in a line with platypus.

Must I use a table or better use the raw canvas?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to have good control over your layout use tables. Otherwise maybe you could also think about `<img>` HTML tags in paragraph flowables.